# Does InvalidateVisual works in a lazy way?

Tags: c#, wpf, custom-controls, rendering, invalidation

If I call `InvalidateVisual` in my custom WPF control, when does the actual layout evaluation and rendering process happen?

Immediately or - similarly as in WinForms - when I finish my processing?

Comment: be aware, InvalidateVisuals() is much more expensive than Form.Invalidate(), becasue it causes a full relayout. If you want to efficiently update WPF visuals without layout, create a DrawingGroup "backingStore", add it to the DrawingContext during OnRender(), and then update the DrawingGroup whenever you want and it'll efficiently repaint the UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The online help answers your question:

Online help for [InvalidateVisual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatevisual.aspx):

> This method calls InvalidateArrange internally.

Online help for [InvalidateArrange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.invalidatearrange.aspx):

> Invalidates the arrange state (layout) for the element. After the invalidation, the element will have its layout updated, **which will occur asynchronously** unless subsequently forced by UpdateLayout.

In other words: `InvalidateVisual` does not have an effect immediately; it waits until your current code has finished (unless you have calls to [UpdateLayout](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.updatelayout.aspx)).

You also can look at Microsoft's reference source: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#q=UIElement.InvalidateArrange . You will see that `InvalidateArrange()` does not call any blocking code; it returns immediately.